# Put devise module into custom module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, module

I am wondering if it is possible to put devise model into subfolder & module.

For example:

/models/back_office/user.rb

```
module BackOffice
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :ldap_authenticatable, :timeoutable, :trackable
  end
end
```

and corresponding controller:

/controllers/back_office/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
module BackOffice
  module Users
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      layout false
      def create
        # Check if user is already signed in. If true, destroy user session.
        # This code prevents logging in if user pressed 'back' button and tried to log in again
        # with improper password.
        sign_out current_user if user_signed_in?
        super
      end

      def after_sign_out_path_for(_resource_or_scope)
        new_user_session_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this approach I am receiving

`somepath/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in 'const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set the class name of the resource that devise should use for authentication by passing the `class_name` option when declaring the auth routes.

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'BackOffice::User'
```

- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for

Comment: Found out this just a few seconds ago. Thanks :)